# Wordpress: Querying a database from within javascipt / jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple postcode search in my wordpress site. The user enters a postcode, clicks search and the browser directs to a new URL based on the postcode entered.

Presently, I have a large switch statement in the onclick handler of the button, which parses the postcode input in a text box and generates some display text and a URL which I then launch using window.open.

It works OK, but as I add more and more postcodes its bloating the code loaded into the browser and it's all visible in dev console. I'm also limited when it comes to making changes as I'm having to go in and modify the code to implement logic directly in my onclick handler. It's a bit of a mess!

What I would like to achieve is to store all of the relevant information in a mysql database, query the DB  when the form button is clicked, and then launch the URL which will be returned by the db query (well, there'll be a bit more logic in the server script than that but ultimately I'll just be returning a URL and some text).

I'm struggling to get my head around how to implement this. It appears the DB queries need to be in PHP on the server and has to be queried asynchronously? I'm getting lost down a rabbit hole of AJAX which I'm struggling to understand!

I'm not looking to asynchronously update content on my page - at the point that we're running code in the onclick handler, we're ready to launch a new page based on the postcode entered. It appears the required solution is a little more complex than I hoped it might be.

Can anybody suggest how I might implement this? Do I have to use PHP & AJAX?

Thanks

Comment: You do not _have to_ use AJAX for this, you can also simply link to a script or WP endpoint directly, and then _redirect_ to the final destination URL from there.

Comment: if you are redirecting to a new page, there is no need for an async call. all the fun in an async call is that you are staying on the same page. basically just remove the onclick handler and (if it's a form), just submit the form as it is. it will send the form to the server, and from there you can add all the logic you need (in PHP of course). at the end just redirect inside the PHP to the desired page.

Comment: Thanks. Its not a form, its a single text box and a button on a page. The click handler just parses whats in the text box and creates a URL to redirect to. The way you have described is how I originally wanted to do it but I couldn't figure out how to pass back the values from the PHP script to the call in javascript/jquery. I thought the calling jscript needed to effect the URL redirect as its in the browser. Can I just pass the search term into the PHP script and have the PHP script redirect the page? That would be much simpler.